# How do I reduce the execution time in my script in PHP?

Tags: php, execution-time

this is my script, it takes too long , how can I improve the execution time ?

SEE THE ALL OF THE COD: [HERE](http://attin.netlogiq.eu/it4profit/feed.txt) !

```
$count_nr_attributes = count($nume);
$csv[0] = $csv_array_attributes[0];
for ($i=0; $i < $csv_array_attributes; $i++) { 

        if ($i > 0){
            $final = "";
            for ($j=1; $j < $count_nr_attributes; $j++) { 
                echo "select val_attr from attributes where id_produs = '$csv_array_attributes[$i]' and nume_attr = '$nume[$j]'";echo "<br>";
                $select = mysql_query("select val_attr from attributes where id_produs = '$csv_array_attributes[$i]' and nume_attr = '$nume[$j]'");
                $count = mysql_num_rows($select);
                if ($count == 1){
                    $row = mysql_fetch_array($select);
                    $final .= $row['val_attr']."%%";
                }else{
                    $final .= "no%%";
                }
            }
            echo "<hr>";

        }
        $csv[$i] = $csv_array_attributes[$i]."%%".$final;
    }
//create CSV
$file = fopen("attributes.csv","w+");
    foreach ($csv as $line){
        fputcsv($file,explode('%%',$line),"^","`");
    }
```

The variable `$count_nr_attributes` contains more then 2500 values and also the $csv_array_attributes contains more then 2500 values. Actually i have two for loops and the execution time takes too long. How can i improve this ? thx

and the query result always return me one value;

Comment: I take it you meant ***decrease*** in the title there... Slightly off-topic, but the `mysql_*` extension is deprecated, stop using it ASAP. Learn to use `mysqli_*` and/or `PDO`

Comment: deacrease, certanly, srry my mistake

Comment: Improve your mysql query so you don't have to create `6 250 000` database queries..

Comment: 2500 x 2500 = 6.25 million queries. That will certainly slow things down yes. Try to re-think your solution. I don't think there is a quick fix for this.

Comment: Could you please provide table description (or better yet a link to http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: see all of my code in my post , I updated it, thx

Answer (score 2):

Each time you're executing a SQL Query, no matter how many result it returns, it takes some time.

The best you can do to decrease the time your script takes, is to put the **query outside the loops**, fetch all the results at once, and process it afterward with your loop.

Comment: I know, but I needed inside. because the array($name) represents the name of each column from my csv. and I have to check for each product id if it has the specific attribute name then get the attribute name(val_attr), else put the string "no".

Comment: Where do you have changed column names??

Answer (score 1):

First of all: don't use mysql_*. Anyway try to redo this with as few queries as possible. I don't have time to analyze all the intentions right now but try something like that:

```
$count_nr_attributes = count($nume);
$csv[0] = $csv_array_attributes[0];

$query = "
SELECT id_produs, nume_attr, val_attr FROM attributes WHERE 
id_produs IN (".implode(",", $csv_array_attributes).") AND nume_attr BETWEEN 0 AND {$count_nr_attributes} 
ORDER BY id_produs";

$res = mysql_query($query);
$lastProduct = -1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
  //do whatever you want
  //just check if id_produs is different than the previous one to emulate
  //$csv[$i] = $csv_array_attributes[$i]."%%".$final;
}
```

Comment: I thought about a similar solutions but I do not know if the resulting statement can be that big.

Comment: 2500 thousand ids is not that much... if needed he can also do some simple batch processing by splitting `$csv_array_attributes`.

Comment: You still run loads of queries. Approach I proposed requires only one which returns huge result.

Answer (score 0):

use associative array with key as the id_produs and its value after that inside loop use again associative array to fetch all records relevant to the first associative array hope it will decrease a little bit time. thankx